# How to avoid OnItemClick when Scrolling ListView Android

Tags: android

I have a listview, where I am implementing on ItemClick Handler. But the problem is that when I scroll the list I sometimes get the onItemClick event.

How to avoid that

Comment: What's the layout of your list items? Does this happen less often to you in existing apps?

Comment: There is no setting for sensitivity that I'm aware of other than overriding all touch methods and creating a pseudo click action with an extended time representing a click. If you're triggering a click action when scrolling it's because of the way you're touching the screen - that's purely user behaviour.

Comment: You could implement an OnScrollListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html and only enable the item click listener when list scrolling is idle. However, I'm pretty sure that the list is in fact idle (or thinks it is idle) when you click an item. It really may be just a sensitivity problem: too old / slow hardware, bad touch screen etc. can lead to a bad fling / swipe recognition and translate to clicks instead. Try to reproduce that problem on different devices.

Comment: Is there something like if the click is for so many msecs then only recongnize it?

Comment: Well, under the hood Android actually does that already and it works usually pretty well. However, it does not work that well on resistive touch screens (where you have a plastic film on the screen and you need to press hard with your finger). I played around with a cheap Android tablet a while ago and it had exactly this problem with scrolling views and lists. Some modern capacitative touch screens can also have small insensitive spots where you cannot swipe correctly. That's the case with my Nexus 7 tablet for example. I'm pretty sure it's a hardware problem.